# Place tics at values stored in variables

Tags: gnuplot

I have used the `stats` command to store the x-postion of absolute maxima in my plot of seven datasets in seven variables, `grN_pos_max_y` with `N` that goes from `1` to `7`. Can I place the tics in the x-axis at the positions specified by these variables?

I tried using

```
$maxima << EOD
gr1_pos_max_y
gr2_pos_max_y
gr3_pos_max_y
gr4_pos_max_y
gr5_pos_max_y
gr6_pos_max_y
gr7_pos_max_y
EOD
```

and then

```
plot ..., \
     $maxima u 1:(NaN):xticlabel(1) notitle
```

but I don't know how to read variables into a data block (if I replace the variable names by their values, however, it works).

---

*Edit:* This is what I want (I plotted it using Ethan's answer)
[image: uber cool plot]

Comment: What do you mean with 7 datasets? 7 files or 7 datablocks or 7 datasets in one file or datablock (separated by empty lines)?

Comment: @theozh It's seven files that I read into variables using `gr1 = "< awk '…' gr1.dat"`, and then I do `plot gr1 using …, gr2 using …`.

Comment: Ok. So, problem solved, question answered? If none of the answers here is acceptable and you found a solution which suits you better than the existing ones, then please answer your own question (with full script and result). Please don't put just a result (without script) in the question, otherwise the question will remain to appear as unanswered which is apparently not true and people won't know how you actually did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want, but this may get you partway there:

```
set xtics add (gr1_pos_max_y, gr2_pos_max_y, gr3_pos_max_y, gr4_pos_max_y, gr5_pos_max_y, gr6_pos_max_y, gr7_pos_max_y)
plot 'whatever'
```

That will get you plain (unlabeled) tic marks in addition to whatever tic marks and labels are being generated automatically.

If you want only these marks and no auto-generated marks, remove the keyword `add`.

If you want to place labels to go with these new tics, change it to:

```
  set xtics add ( "Max 1" gr1_pos_maxy,  "Max 2" gr2_pos_maxy, ...
```

This is all assuming you want these tics to label a plot that contains something other than the tics themselves.  If you want only a plot of these y values, perhaps as impulses?, please re-phrase the question or show a sketch of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks! I've been able to do what I wanted and I've put the result in the question. Just for the record, I got the idea from http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/varigrid.html and the code of my attempt was adapted from there, basically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `awk`, you can do it all in gnuplot.

- put `stats` into a loop and write the `STATS` values into a datablock `$Maxima`
- plot your data and `$Maxima` as Ethan suggested `with impulses`
- you can also plot the maxima y-value as labels in the graph

The script needs to be adapted depending on your file naming scheme.

**Script:**

```
### extract maxima from several files
reset session

N = 7
myFile(n) = sprintf("SO72750257_%d.dat",n)

# create some "random" test data
do for [n=1:N] {
    set table myFile(n)
        f(x) = -a*(x-x0)**2 +y0
        x0 = (n-1)*10./N + rand(0)*10./N
        a  = rand(0)*50+10
        y0 = rand(0)*80+20
        plot [0:10] '+' u 1:(f(x))
    unset table
}

# extract maxima
set print $Maxima
    do for [n=1:N] {
        stats myFile(n) u 1:2 nooutput
        print sprintf("%.1f %.1f", STATS_pos_max_y, STATS_max_y)
    }
set print

set yrange[0:]
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.1, 0
set xtics ()    # remove all xtics 
set key out noautotitle

plot for [i=1:N] myFile(i) u 1:2 w l ti sprintf("Set %d",i), \
     $Maxima u 1:2:($0+1):xtic(1) w impulses lc var dt 2, \
     $Maxima u 1:2:2 w labels offset 0, char 1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Awk was for cleaning up the input files: the `grN` variables, assigned to `"< awk …"`, contain the coordinates of the points to plot, then I did `do for [i=1:7]{eval "stats gr".i." using 1:2 name 'gr".i."'"}`. Aside from that thanks, it's very instructive :-)